# Trying to browse and insert an image file in to an OLE object field.

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to browse and insert an image into a field in my form 'partimage' with click of a button.

Here is the code I have so far to do this..

When I click on the browse button it will allow me to select the image, but it won't insert that image into the part image box in my form.. 
Can anyone tell me how i can fix this?

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim f    As Object
 Set f = Application.FileDialog(1)
 f.AllowMultiSelect = False
 f.Show

 If f.Show Then
            Me![partimage].Picture = f.SelectedItems
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your form's code module include `Option Explicit` in its Declarations section?  If not, add it, and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about and then attempt compile again.  Keep doing that until no more compile errors.

Comment: how do i check the forms code module?..

Comment: nvm.. nvm.. i did it. included that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f.SelectedItems` is a *FileDialogSelectedItems* Object --- a collection of file or folder names.  Since you have `AllowMultiSelect = False`, the user can choose only one item.  And that item will be the first item in the collection.  Add this line to see the full path of the selected item:

```vb
MsgBox f.SelectedItems(1)
```

Also you need call `f.Show` only once.  Remove the first `f.Show` call and keep only this one: `If f.Show Then`

Don't even worry about setting `Me![partimage].Picture` until after you verify your code retrieves the file's path string correctly.

```vb
Private Sub Command3_Click()
    Dim f    As Object
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(1)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    'f.Show

    If f.Show Then
        'MsgBox f.SelectedItems(1)
        Me![partimage].Picture = f.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. i changed the code according to what u said and it does give me the correct path. 
But i need to insert that image in to partimage.

Comment: `Me![partimage].Picture = f.SelectedItems(1)` That's what worked for me.  I added the code I tested to the answer.

Comment: I tried that, but i am getting an error saying that Object doesn't support this property or method. 

Run time error 438

Comment: I put : `
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim f    As Object
 Set f = Application.FileDialog(1)
 f.AllowMultiSelect = False
 If f.Show Then
    Me![partdescription].Picture = f.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
 
End Sub`

Comment: When Access displays the error message, click the Debug button.  Your code will be displayed with the line which triggered the error highlighted in yellow.  Which line is that?

Comment: `Me![partdescription].Picture = f.SelectedItems(1)`

Comment: `partdescription` instead of `partimage`?  So what type of control is `partdescription`?  If `partdescription` is a text box, it won't have a `.Picture` property and it can not display an image.

Comment: Sorry it should be partimage . i was just playing around with it to see where i was getting the error.